# Why does the Enterprise-D use such a silly plan in The Outcast?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Star Trek TNG Season 5 Episode 17 ("The Outcast"), the Enterprise-D send a shuttle into a "pocket of null space", to rescue another small ship in there. There's an energy drain issue, so they buttress the shuttle's systems with an extra battery. Then they go in, waste all their energy, and barely make it out.

That seems like a silly plan:

First, there's the fact that almost everything in TNG should be doable unmanned, including most of what the bridge crew does, but let's forget about that since it would knock the entire premise of the series.

1. Why could they not have sent the shuttle, unmanned, on a fixed circular course which takes it in and out of the pocket, to gauge the energy drain levels?
2. Why not use a Runabout, which is probably better equipped to store more energy?
3. Inside the pocket, if the transporting is what drains most of the energy, why not just do EVA and manually move the J'naii from the other ship?
4. So, the first transport attempt fails. Why not go back out, recharge the battery, talk to Engineering about it and have another go?

Comment: They don't have runabouts on the Enterprise-D

Comment: @Valorum: Sure they do, they [used this one](https://www.neutralzone.de/database/Federation/Starfleet/Danube_Runabout_Enterprise-D03.htm) in Timescape.

Comment: There was only one seen, and it was destroyed

Comment: You only need to watch about a season of any Star Trek series to conclude that the themes of the stories and/or highlighting of the characters is a much higher priority for the writers than, well, anything else. Trying to unpack the science or logic of any plot or event is almost always going to be disappointing or confusing

Comment: @Valorum: Shuttles get destroyed on occassion... even in the OutCast they lost one. But we know the Enterprise-D is like a small port, after all: Shuttle Bay 1 is two decks high and has lots and lots of craft.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Sometimes there are minor considerations that one misses. Like whether or not the ship is supposed to have runabouts to spare :-)

Comment: The Federation is a post-scarcity society, but people still need a purpose in life, so sometimes automation isn’t used even when it may make sense.

Comment: The EVA idea sounds extremely risky; even assuming it's possible to EVA out of a shuttle (by evacuating the atmosphere to space?), fast enough to avoid too much energy drain, and not too energy-intensive to restore the atmosphere, how do they know they can get inside the *Taris Murn* when _it_ is drained?  It would need to have an airlock, because there's no way to get the unconscious crew safely into suits otherwise, and it would need enough remaining power to operate the airlock.

Answer (score 4):

> Why could they not have sent the shuttle, unmanned, on a fixed circular course which takes it in and out of the pocket, to gauge the energy drain levels?

When the Enterprise approaches the pocket, nothing is known about how it looks from the inside, since it's completely invisible to the sensors:

> **RIKER**: We think your system contains one of these null pockets. If we're right, **the pocket would absorb electromagnetic energy from anything that entered it**.
> **SOREN**: Like a shuttlecraft.
> **RIKER**: Or a probe. Making them powerless.
> **SOREN**: But outside the pocket, all the energy is bent around it, making it naturally cloaked. That's why we cannot see it, **and our sensors cannot read it**.

(Emphasis mine, all quotes from [chakoteya.net](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/217.htm) )

The pocket messing with the sensors could in itself already be a reason why an automated flight is ruled out, and at this point it's reasonable to assume that no communication can go out of the pocket to the Enterprise, so just plotting a random course hoping for the probe to return, and then sending it back in on a different course is much more complicated than just flying over there and having a good look at it.

> Why not use a Runabout, which is probably better equipped to store more energy?

Apart from the fact that Runabouts were rarely seen in TNG, you are looking at this with the benefit of hindsight. Sure, a Runabout might have been better, but while they were preparing for the mission, they thought a shuttle would work out OK. Also, not the amount of energy stored seems to be the problem, but reducing the drain:

> **RIKER**: We can send one of our own shuttles, but its energy would also be absorbed. **Our Chief Engineer is working on a way to maintain the power reserves long enough to rescue your crew**.

> Inside the pocket, if the transporting is what drains most of the energy, why not just do EVA and manually move the J'naii from the other ship?

There are at least three reasons I can think of:

- There is no reason to believe that an EVA would work, since an EVA suit would also be affected by the energy drain
- Soren is a scientist, Riker would most likely have to do the rescuing alone for two affected members of the crew
- It would also take more time, and timing is of essence, since they have no idea in what condition the crew is in

That last point is backed up by the following briefing Riker has for LaForge:

> **LAFORGE**: Then that's it. Commander, I'll monitor you as far as I can, but once you get inside that pocket you're on your own.
> **RIKER**: **We don't have any idea what condition the shuttle crew is in**, so we'll all beam directly to Sickbay.

> So, the first transport attempt fails. Why not go back out, recharge
> the battery, talk to Engineering about it and have another go?

Because, as mentioned above, timing is of essence. Additionally, the effect of the transporter on the power drain is much bigger than Riker anticipates, because he explicitly states that they have enough power for a second attempt:

> **SOREN**: We used ten megajoules with that attempt. We're down to thirty four percent of reserves.
> **RIKER**: We can give it one more try. **More than that, we won't have enough power to get ourselves out of here**.